# Django-admin: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/plans/plan/

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.10, django-plans

I'm trying to make [Django-plans](https://github.com/cypreess/django-plans) app work. Everything seems to be working except `/admin/plans/plan/` ( `/admin/plans/order/`,  `/admin/plans/userplan/` etc. works correctly).

When I click on plan in **Django-admin** it returns:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/plans/plan/
```

I can't figure out why it wouldn't exists. I took a look at `django-plans` admin.py file and it seems that `Plan` doesn't have any special template specified.

Do you know what's the problem?

**TRACEBACK**

```
Environment: Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/plans/plan/

Django Version: 1.10.5 Python Version: 2.7.10 Installed Applications: ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'django.contrib.sites',  'authapp',  'presentationapp',  'allauth',  'allauth.account',  'allauth.socialaccount',  'djmoney_rates',  'djmoney',  'api',  'productapp',  'django_extensions',  'mainapp',  'django_tables2',  'engineapp',  'dashboardapp',  'ticketapp',  'celery',  'dbbackup',  'bootstrap3',  'django_filters',  'widget_tweaks',  'cacheapp',  'adminapp',  'djcelery',  'import_export',  'plans',  'request',  'django.contrib.humanize'] Installed Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  'authapp.middleware.BasicAuthMiddleware',  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  'request.middleware.RequestMiddleware',  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\authapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\presentationapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\productapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\mainapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\engineapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\dashboardapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\bootstrap3\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\FS Dropbox\Dropbox\priceist\adminapp\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\djcelery\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\import_export\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\plans\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\request\templates\ordered_model\admin\order_controls.html (Source does not exist)


Template error: In template C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_list.html, error at line 82    ordered_model/admin/order_controls.html   72 :     {% endif %}    73 :       {% endblock %}    74 :     75 :       <form id="changelist-form" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>{% csrf_token %}   76 :       {% if cl.formset %}    77 :         <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>    78 :       {% endif %}    79 :  80 :       {% block result_list %}    81 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}    82 :            {% result_list cl %}     83 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}    84 :       {% endblock %}    85 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}    86 :       </form>    87 :     </div>    88 :   </div>    89 : {% endblock %}    90 : 

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  68.             reraise(exc, self.backend)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in reraise
  89.     six.reraise(exc.__class__, new, sys.exc_info()[2])

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in render
  225.         _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in result_list
  339.             'results': list(results(cl))}

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in results
  315.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in __init__
  306.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  217.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in lookup_field
  286.             value = attr(obj)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\ordered_model\admin.py" in move_up_down_links
  69.             'query_string': self.request_query_string

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\DropboxWorkspaces\priceist_workspace\priceist_venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/plans/plan/ Exception Value: ordered_model/admin/order_controls.html
```

I can't get in Plans, other pages works correctly.

[image]

Comment: A hacky solution would be to create a blank app called 'admin', and add it to INSTALLED_APPS (at the very bottom). The admin app will have templates folder and another folder called 'admin' inside templates folder. Then you can have 'plans' folder inside 'admin' folder. As an alternative, you can also add an 'admin' folder to apps you already have.

Comment: @user2707389 I would like to know what's the problem, why django can't find such template. Do you know? thanks

Comment: I will explain the way django looks for templates: in your case, it goes through all the 'templates' folder inside each of the apps included in INSTALLED_APPS and looks for 'admin' folder as it is where 'plans' folder lives. In your case, there is no 'admin' folder anywhere and it is raising the error. Just make an admin folder inside any template folder inside any app and it should work. Or put your code on github and let me know.

Comment: I tried to add admin folder inside one of my apps an it did not help. I would be surprised if it helped because I can acces other models of Plan app. I've added a screenshot at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I posted the correct answer below for this problem. Creating a dummy folder is not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else encountering this *exact* error, the issue is that you are using `django-ordered-model` package, but you have not added `ordered_model` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.